# I'm trying to create a broken horizontal line with arrows on either end and text in the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive horizontal line with arrows on either end and text in the middle.  I found ways to create the line with the text in the middle using before and after, but I'm stumped as to how to incorporate the arrows on either end. Ideally I would like to use a font icon, but am willing to use a generic html arrow if necessary.

[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful to see your existing code, so we can understand how you've approached this problem already. Have you already attempted this with just CSS triangles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you can achieve it:

- Have the image as background.
- Center align the text.
- Give the text some background colour, matching the parent background colour.

**Snippet**

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("http://www.signsbypost.com/sites/default/files/irun/uc_product/images/SELF-ADHESIVE-VINYL-STICK-ON-ARROW-DOUBLE-HEAD-5271.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Hello</span></h1>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of using a background behind the text. I might try this.

Answer (score 1):

Only using CSS without images.

```css
.line {
 margin-top:8px;
 width:10%;
 background:blue;
 height:3px;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}
.arrowed .text{
 padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.arrowed span{
float:left;
display:block;
}

.line.first:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: -3px;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid blue;
}

.line.second:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -3px;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="arrowed">
  <span class="line first"></span>
  <span class="text">Continuous Improvement</span>
  <span class="line second"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Okay, yes, thank you. This is close to what I'm playing with, but yours works and mine doesn't. However, this solution adds the before and after arrows to every <p> instance. So I changed it to a header style I'll only use when I want this style. 2 Questions: Can I avoid the break between the line and arrow? Can I make the line responsive so it doesn't split on smaller screens?

Comment: It should work fine now I have updated the code, I almost make the line percentage instead of fixed width that could fix your issues but you might need to add responsive breakpoint for some smaller devices to fine tune it to not break it.

Comment: That's great thank you!  Is there any way to keep the arrowed lines from dropping to the next line in smaller devices?